# Add string to pandas dataframe column with multiple comma-separated values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe containing a string prefix and values from another column. The column containing the values has instances of multiple comma separated values. For example:

```
MIMNumber      
102610
114080,601079
```

I would like for the dataframe to look like this:

```
MIMNumber       OMIM_Link
102610  https://www.omim.org/entry/102610
114080,601079   https://www.omim.org/entry/114080,https://www.omim.org/entry/601079
```

I've tried this:

```
df['OMIM_Link'] = df['MIMNumber'].map('https://www.omim.org/entry/{}'.format)
```

But this does not add the string prefix to all instances where there are multiple comma separated values:

```
MIMNumber       OMIM_Link
102610  https://www.omim.org/entry/102610
114080,601079   https://www.omim.org/entry/114080,601079
```

I've also tried this:

```
url = 'https://www.omim.org/entry/'
df['OMIM_Link'] = df['MIMNumber'].apply(url.join)
```

But the string prefix is joined between each value:

```
MIMNumber       OMIM_Link
102610  1https://www.omim.org/entry/0https://www.omim.org/entry/2https://www.omim.org/entry/6https://www.omim.org/entry/1https://www.omim.org/entry/0
114080,601079   1https://www.omim.org/entry/1https://www.omim.org/entry/4https://www.omim.org/entry/0https://www.omim.org/entry/8https://www.omim.org/entry/0https://www.omim.org/entry/,https://www.omim.org/entry/6https://www.omim.org/entry/0https://www.omim.org/entry/1https://www.omim.org/entry/0https://www.omim.org/entry/7https://www.omim.org/entry/9
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the comma by `,https://www.omim.org/entry/` and add `https://www.omim.org/entry/` at start.

```py
df['OMIM_Link'] = 'https://www.omim.org/entry/' + df['MIMNumber'].str.replace(',', ',https://www.omim.org/entry/')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try regex replace

```py
df['out'] = df['MIMNumber'].replace(r'(\d+)', r'https://www.omim.org/entry/\1', regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

       MIMNumber  \
0         102610
1  114080,601079

                                                                   out
0                                    https://www.omim.org/entry/102610
1  https://www.omim.org/entry/114080,https://www.omim.org/entry/601079
```

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this here in case you have a variety of domains/paths:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MIMNumber': ['102610', '114080,601079'],
                   'OMIM_Link': ['https://www.omim.org/entry/',
'https://www.omim.org/entry/,https://www.omim.org/entry/']})

for i in range(len(df)):
    mim = df['MIMNumber'][i]
    if "," in mim:
        mim = mim.split(",")
        link = df['OMIM_Link'][i].split(",")
        df['OMIM_Link'][i] = ",".join(['{o}{m}'.format(o=link[i], m=mim[i])
                                   for i in range(len(link))])
    else:
        link = df['OMIM_Link'][i]
        df['OMIM_Link'][i] = '{o}{m}'.format(o=link, m=mim)

print(df)
```

which does what you want:

```
       MIMNumber                                          OMIM_Link
0         102610                  https://www.omim.org/entry/102610
1  114080,601079  https://www.omim.org/entry/114080,https://www....
```